# Updating using `database/sql` in Go is slow

Tags: mysql, go

I'm running an update query against a local MySQL instance, and it seems to be taking about 8 ms to update a single row. That seemed really slow. Is there anything I can do to improve performance?

```
db, _ := sql.Open("mysql", "user:pass@(localhost:3306)/dbname")
db.Exec(`CREATE TABLE topics(
            topic_id                            INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            title                               VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
            content                             TEXT,
            is_sticky                           BOOL NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
            is_readonly                         BOOL NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
            num_comments                        INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
            num_views                           INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
            activity_at                         DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
            archived_at                         DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
            created_at                          DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
            updated_at                          DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);`)
db.Exec("INSERT INTO topics(title) VALUES(?);", "Name")

since := time.Now()
for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
    db.Exec("UPDATE topics SET num_views = ? WHERE topic_id = 1;", i)
}
fmt.Println(time.Since(since))
```

It takes about 850 ms to complete 100 iterations on a Core i7-4790K. I also tried the same thing with Postgres with more or less the same result. I created this test code because my webapp was very slow at about 10 ms per request (250 requests/sec throughput) and it turned out that updates were taking a lot of time.

Also, using prepared statements made no difference.

```
stmt, _ := db.Prepare("UPDATE topics SET num_views = ? WHERE topic_id = ?;")
since := time.Now()
for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
    stmt.Exec(i, 1)
}
fmt.Println(time.Since(since))
```

Comment: You could use a single query instead of a hundred (at least in PostgreSQL, not sure if MySQL has native support for that as well, but I assume it does).

Comment: @mkopriva Yes, I expect a single query or putting them all in a transaction will help, but my problem is that a single update is slow which is leading to poor performance in my webapp's HTTP handlers.

Comment: Something's up with your db setup, or something, does not look to be a Go issue: https://imgur.com/LjHdDtn (postgres, ~6ms on my machine)

Comment: check if any lock are preventing the update, but you should look for othe rmeans to save the views.

Comment: *"my webapp was very slow at about 10 ms per request"* -- @spiky you are not doing `sql.Open` per every request I hope, or are you?

Comment: @mkopriva thanks for running it on your machine! I'm still don't know what the problem is, but thanks pointing me in a direction other than Go -- I'll try it on another workstation.

Comment: @mkopriva LOL, no. I'm not doing `sql.Open` on every request!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Speaking from a MySQL point of view...)

Some "Rules of Thumb":

- Single `INSERT`: 10ms
- 100 or more rows inserted by a single `INSERT`:  10 times as fast per row.
- `BEGIN;  INSERT...; INSERT...; ... COMMIT;` : Also 10x.
- The above assumes HDD; SSD might be another 10x faster.
- If multiple connections are each doing inserts, they *may* be able to run in parallel.  10 threads might be able to do 5 times the work in the same elapsed time.  (Of course, this *may* add unwanted complexity to the app.)

Similar figures for `UPDATE`, though it is not easy to do different updates on different rows with a single query.

Your test shows 8.5ms per row `UPDATEd` when doing one row at a time.  Batching either with `BEGIN...COMMIT` will probably take about 85ms for all 100 rows, even on HDD.

Some applications lend themselves to batching; some do not.  If you want to talk about improving MySQL performance, we need to get into the details of your application.

"Like" and "View" counters *may* need to be moved to a 'parallel' table since they tend to be Updated one-at-a-time, with some interference with other activity.  They also tend to automatically allow for multi-threading, hence much less than 850ms per 100.  In really high activity (over, say, 1K views per second), such counters can be artificially batched via extra app code.

Please rewrite your benchmark to reflect the activity that will happen in the real application.  (I am *guessing* that the Updates will happen in parallel, not serial.  And they will be spread out randomly across time.)

Another thing...  If each "view count" comes to a web server, then there is also connect and disconnect; hence the *elapsed* time is likely to be more than 8.5ms.  But "elapsed" is not the critical issue; the real issue is "how many updates can be performed per second".)

And another thing...  If you test 'parallel', don't hit the same row by each request.  That will probably be much slower than if you hit different rows.  (Hitting a random row would be better.  Having a bias in which row to hit would be even more realistic.)

Comment: I switched to asynchronous commit in Postgres, and the time for 100 sequential updates dropped from 850ms to 8ms. What is the equivalent in MySQL for `synchronous_commit=OFF`?

Comment: The update statement is in an endpoint that is called to update the number of views of a topic. So, it gets called on every page load.

Comment: In MySQL, setting `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit` to 0 or 2 reduced the update time for 100 updates to 12ms.

Comment: @spiky - I doubt if MySQL has an exact analog of `synchronous_commit`.  See `sync_binlog`, "semi-sync replication", `autocommit`, and the one you mentioned.  I do not believe there is a flag that will make 100 updates run 100x faster, even with risk of lost data.

Comment: @spiky - Are you using Primary-Replica replication?  Or are you concerned only about a single server?

Comment: I'm only looking at single server right now.